# How can I get the value of an object property in jquery?

Tags: jquery, object

I have a group of objects on my page. I want to get the first one, so I do this:

```
var tmpLi = li.first();
console.dir(tmpLi);
```

This works fine; it returns this in firebug:

[image]

I need to return the value of the outerHTML element, but can't seem to figure out how to get it. I've tried:

```
var tmpLi = li.first().data("outerHTML");
```

and

```
var tmpLi = li.first().attr("outerHTML");
```

both of which return "undefined". Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `DOM` object for `outerHTML` instead of jQuery object so `convert` it to DOM object to access outerHTML property.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TtNkK/)**

```
var tmpLi = li.first()[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: I tried, this, and it printed out "There are no child objects".

Comment: Oops, never mind. Needed to change from `console.dir` to `console.log` and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

It returns an object, so you have to access it like the following.
`li.first()[0].outerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

You either need to use the [`prop` method](http://api.jquery.com/prop), which gets the underlying object's property value:

```
li.first().prop('outerHTML');
```

...or unwrap the DOM object from the jQuery selection:

```
li[0].outerHTML
```